# Finding the index of the minimum and maximum values in a NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm working on a small data analysis assignment with a dataset of NBA players and several attributes, such as height, weight, etc. Here is a small sample of the dataset:

```
players = ['Aaron Gordon', 'Aaron Holiday', 'Abdel Nader', 'Al Horford', 'Al-Farouq Aminu']
years_old = [23, 22, 25, 32, 28]
height_inches = [81, 73, 78, 82, 81]
weight_pounds = [220, 185, 225, 245, 220]
```

I'm trying to create a program that finds the indexes of the shortest and tallest players in this dataset. I've converted these lists into NumPy arrays, and I'm able to successfully find the smallest and tallest players, but I'm not sure how to get the index of those particular players.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
np_players = np.array(players)
np_years_old = np.array(years_old)
np_height_inches = np.array(height_inches)
np_weight_pounds = np.array(weight_pounds)

def shortest_player(np_h):
  mask = np.argmin(np_h)
  idx = np.where(mask)
  return idx

def tallest_player(np_h):
  mask = np.argmax(np_h)
  idx = np.where(mask)
  return idx
```

This is the error I receive when I try to test these functions while running the following line `print(players[ shortest_player(np_height_meters) ] )`:

> TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in () 9 return idx 10 ---> 11
>   print(players[tallest_player(np_height_meters)]) TypeError: list
>   indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

As an example, in the sample dataset provided, the functions would ideally return 1 for the shortest player and 3 for the tallest player.

Any insight or advice?

Comment: How are you calling these function, what is the full error message (including stack trace)?

Comment: `print(players[ shortest_player(np_height_meters) ] )` is how I call it. The full error message is: `---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-100-6fbae5f83c73> in <module>()
      9   return idx
     10 
---> 11 print(players[tallest_player(np_height_meters)])

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`

Comment: @Aspire please see the edit in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the numpy arrays you could simply use the argmax/argmin functions:

```
min_h_idx = np.argmin(np_height_inches)
max_h_idx = np.argmax(np_height_inches)
```

and symmetrically for the weights.

Here is a simple output your posted values:

```
>>> height_inches = [81, 73, 78, 82, 81]
>>> np_height_inches = np.array(height_inches)
>>> np.argmin(np_height_inches)
1
>>> np.argmax(np_height_inches)
3
```

**Note**

After the addition of the error and line tried to be executed there is an issue with the parameter passed to the function `np_height_meters` its not appear in the piece of code you added.
As for the output after changing from `np_height_meters` to `np_height_inches` and removing the just using the `argmin/argmax` without the `where` function:

```
def shortest_player(np_h):
  idx = np.argmin(np_h)
  return idx

def tallest_player(np_h):
  idx = np.argmax(np_h)
  return idx

print(players[ shortest_player(np_height_inches) ] )
```

the output I get changing to the above:

```
Aaron Holiday
```

Comment: When I try that, it returns the actual shortest and tallest player names, not their indices.

Comment: @Aspire you can look at the simple output, the values are indices